# python gdown DistributionNotFound; Error during file is exe

Tags: python

I get an error when I have the file as an EXE but I get no error when the file is PY.
My code is:

```
import gdown

url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=18TFG11iQl2de6afdTE9802IHBL7Bq0Tn'
output = 'C:\TakeNotes_Temp\TakeNotes.zip'
gdown.download ( url, output, quiet = False )
```

This code works perfectly in a PY file but when I use pyinstaller and make it into an EXE I get this error:
[image: Error]

What can be the problem? I executed this command to covert to EXE:

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --name "test" --log-level "DEBUG"  "C:/Desktop/Python/Test.py"

Python version 3.9.1; Pyinstaller version 4.1; Pip up to date ( Latest version ).

Please do help me! Any replies will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by switching from gdown to Google Drive Downloader:

```
from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader as g

g.download_file_from_google_drive ( file_id = '1cqjRLBrgrlSI7KR3VNa64A4l0_TpOB3z', dest_path = 'C:\Desktop\test.zip', unzip = True )
```